# Android service completely wrecks performance of device?

Tags: java, android, service, timer, handler

I have a service that needs to check if a certain application is in the foreground.  When the application exits the foreground, the service will run a command.  Right now, I have this implemented with a timer:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startid) {
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Service has started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
     });

    Timer timer  =  new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() 
        {
            /* Get all Tasks available (with limit set). */
            ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> allTasks = mgr.getRunningTasks(showLimit);
            /* Loop through all tasks returned. */
            for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : allTasks) 
            {                  
                Log.i("MyApp", "Task: " + aTask.baseActivity.getClassName()); 

                if (aTask.baseActivity.getClassName().equals("package")) {
                    running=true;
                    }
                else {
                    RunAsRoot(commandsdefault);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 6000, 3000);  // every 3 seconds, with a 6 second first execution delay


    return START_STICKY;

}
```

Which is great, it works as intended.  But it's eating up an enormous amount of CPU time, and the UI for all applications, even the launcher, is jumpy.  Is there a better method of doing this?

Comment: Also remember that applications are running slower when are plugged to debugger

Comment: You could should maybe consider to use and handler with a postDelayed runnable as explained here: http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/ instead of the TimerTask

Answer (score 2):

probably mgr.getRunningTasks(showLimit); is taking lot of resources..you can reduce "showLimit" value and check the difference.

You can also try calling http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/com/android/internal/app/IUsageStats.java through reflection if you planning to build app usage manager kind of app...

Comment: I believe that was it!  I reduced it to 2 rather than twenty, and I don't see any performance hits now.  I'll report back soon, thanks.